# iphone semulator loading problem?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I develop a iphone application using cocos2d.But after including the sound file a loading problem is found. I am not understand why the problem is occur. I send link an image(get from consol).In this image the error is showing. [link text](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/131/picture100.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename or delete Divx Decoder. This is becoming a well known/wide spread problem apparently!